# Ajax call to ColdFusion CFC in IE9 not completing, OK in other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, mozilla, coldfusion-10

I have a number of Ajax calls set up in my ColdFusion 10 web application to update information in a shopping cart. These all work like a charm in various versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE 10 and 11. However, they act unpredictably in IE9, and sometimes not at all. In troubleshooting this, I ran a call to one CFC that wasn't returning anything from IE 9 in both IE and Firefox 23. In the CFC in question, I set it to simply return the word "boo", and send the readyState, responseText, status and statusText to the Javascript console in the Developer tools for each. In both, I get readyState=4, status=200 and statusText="OK". However, in FF the responseText came back "boo" (as expected) and in IE it came back 0.

Here's my Ajax call for this example:

```
var thisCall = $.ajax({
    url: "remote.cfc?method=updateTarget&target="+thisID+"&returnFormat=JSON",
    type: "get",
    async:false,
    success: function(status) {
        return status;
        }
    });
```

Here's my CFC:

```
<cffunction name="updateTarget" access="remote" returnformat="json" output="false" hint="update target">
    <cfargument name="target" required="yes" type="string">

    <cfreturn 'boo'> <!--- added for troubleshooting --->
    <cfset session.user.target = Arguments.target>

    <cfset status = updateSubtotal()>

    <cfset status = SerializeJSON(status)>
    <cfreturn status>
</cffunction>
```

I've tried this with async:true in the Ajax call and output="true" in the CFC, with no difference. Other calls to similar CFCs elsewhere in my code work reliably in Mozilla and newer IE browsers, but unpredictably in IE9.

Comment: What do you get if you omit jQuery, and just browse to the URL directly in IE9? Oh... and which version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: When I tried browsing directly, I found the problem with this particular example: the value for the variable 'thisID' had spaces in it. Apparently, IE9 can't handle white space. So I added a check for white space in the variable 'thisID' and replaced each space with a '-' (it's not a character that will be in use for the possible values for this variable). I strip these out in my CFC and it seems to work. I'll check my other calls to see if that might come into play with them as well.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1. I'll try an older version and see if that works.

Comment: A followup: after making the above change in the variable used in the Ajax call, it fixed the problem I was having with inconsistent behavior in other methods invoked by Ajax call. Those methods were dependent on the outcome of this call. I ended up not having to go back to an older version of jQuery.

Thanks much, Adam, your question answered mine.

Comment: Cool! Do you wanna post your comment as an answer, and mark it answered? (so other people know you don't need help with this any more).

Comment: Hold on, looks like I'm not out of the woods yet. Still having a problem with completing calls.

I am finding that after about 5 or 6 clicks in IE9, each of which calls a method updating the cart, it appears that either the browser or the jQuery method stops sending requests. I confirmed this by having the CFC method email me the state of the cart at the start and end of the call. After 5 or 6 clicks, I get no more responses from my methods. This is not the case with IE10/11, FF or Chrome. When I clear the cache and session and try again in IE9, it works for about 5 or 6 clicks and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my second issue: IE9's Ajax response caching prevents calls from going out after a certain number have been made. FF, Chrome and later versions of IE do not do this by default. To make this work in IE9, I changed the type to POST. Now it works the same as any other browser.

To reiterate the answer to the first problem, IE9 is thrown off by white space in the url attribute of the $.ajax() method. To get around this, I replaced white spaces in the variable referenced in the url query, and restored them in the CFC method receiving the call.

Making these two changes made my Ajax calls work the same in IE9 as in FF, Chrome and later versions of IE.